# Converting euler angle rotations to Axis + Angle

Tags: opengl, 3d, openscenegraph, babylonjs

My goal is to allow users to upload 3D models and position them using their web browser.  To do this, I am using BabylonJS - & its working fine.  After that, I want my users to then be able to view the same model in a native app with the same positioning as set using the web browser.  The framework I'm using for the native app is OpenSceneGraph (OSG).  The problem I have is that I can't get rotation working properly such that OpenSceneGraph correctly mirrors what's happening in BabylonJS.

I'm using Euler angles in BabylonJS - as they are easy for website users to understand (e.g. rotate it 90 degrees around the X axis, and 180 degrees around the Y, and 0 degrees around the Z; e.g. model.rotation = new BABYLON.Vec3(90,180,0)).  OSG however uses the OpenGL glrotate() function which requires an axis of rotation, and the angle to rotate.  To do this I'm using BabylonJS to create a Quaternion from the Euler angles; and then using a function I wrote based off the Java example on this page:

http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/quaternionToAngle/index.htm

```
function getAxisAngle(){
    var q = BABYLON.Quaternion.RotationYawPitchRoll(m.rotation.y,     m.rotation.x, m.rotation.z),s,r={};
    /*Convert quaternion to axis+angle*/
    if(q.w > 1){
        q = q.normalise();
    }
    r.angle = BABYLON.Tools.ToDegrees(2 * Math.acos(q.w));
    s = Math.sqrt(1-q.w*q.w);
    if(s < 0.001){
       r.ax = q.x;
       r.ay = q.y;
       r.az = q.z;
    }else{
       r.ax = q.x / s;
       r.ay = q.y / s; 
       r.az = q.z / s;
    }
    return r;
}
```

I realize a fundamental difference between BJS and OSG is that BJS is left handed coordinate system; and OSG is right handed; so I've made OSG left handed by setting face winding to Clockwise; and scaling the z axis of my models by -1.

Its working at a basic level if I isolate 1 axis at a time; e.g. if I only rotate around the y axis; and don't rotate around any other axis - it looks fine.  However if I try and combine two or three euler angles at the same time; I can't get it to look the same in OSG.

I've read that euler angles are not recommended; partly because the order in which the rotation is applied to each axis matters.. Is this a possible cause?

Comment: I'm guessing since you are using quaternions on one end and using Euler Angles on the other end that you are familiar with the difference of advantages between using Quaternions against Euler Angles due to Gimbal Lock. If your application is using Euler Angles to do rotations across multiple axis of rotation and Gimbal Lock occurs, then your rotations quit working. If you prefer to continue to use Euler Angles for doing rotations on your axis, then  you will need to restrain them between to prevent the Gimbal Lock for example [-89.99, 89.99]. (...continued)

Comment: (...continued) The reason for Gimbal Lock is due to 90 Degrees or PI/4 being a Right Angle or being Orthogonal. Sine (90) or Sine (PI/4) = 1, Cosine(90) or Cosine(PI/4) = 0 and since Tangent = Sine / Cosine here your Tangent is Undefined because of Division By 0. So When you rotation an object on the X - Axis by 90 then by Y or Z either by 90 or -90 what happens is those two axis become interlocked and when you go to rotate again from either of the two locked axis; the function can not determine which axis to rotate. (...continued)

Comment: (...continued) You can check this video out the get a clear understanding of Quaternions, maybe not so much mathematically but at least visually. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zc8b2Jo7mno

Comment: @Francis Cugler You should make it an answer.

Comment: Yes I am familiar with the concept of gimbal lock and how quaternions are superior in this regard.. Actually I'm using quaternions and Eulers on one end and axis + angle on the other end.  I'm just using quaternion as an interchange format from which to calculate the axis + angle rotation based on euler angles.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, do not try to make OSG left-handed, rather translate the "logical" meaning of your rotation angles and apply them to OSG the way it is meant to be used.

Place your loaded model under an osg::PositionAttitudeTransform (or MatrixTransform), then compute the correct rotation (attitude) to apply to it by concatenating 2 quaternions for the 2 rotation angles you expose to the user.
For instance, if you consider "pitching" as a rotation around X axis, and "heading" around Y, do something like:

```
osg::Quat attitude = osg::Quat(pitchAngle, osg::X_AXIS) * osg::Quat(headAngle, osg::Y_AXIS);
transform->setAttitude(attitude);
```

You might have to invert the angle signs to get the correct result (passing from left to right hand).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion will give it a try and report back!